# isin pandas dataframe from 2 other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'countries':['US','UK','Germany','China','India','Pakistan','lanka'],
               'id':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']})
```

also i have two more dataframes. df2 and df3.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'countries':['Germany','China'],
               'capital':['c','d']})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'countries':['lanka','USA'],
               'capital':['g','a']})
```

i want to find the rows in df where df is in df2 and df3

i had this code:

```
df[df.id.isin(df2.capital)]
```

but it will find the rows which is in df2.

is there any way i can do it for both df2 and df3 in a single code.

i'e rows from df where df is in df2 and df3

Comment: Did you bother to try `df[(df.id.isin(df2.capital)) & (df.id.isin(df3.capital))]`?

Comment: Well then your question is ill formed, you've stated you wanted rows in both df2 and df2 which is what I suggested. Are you after rows which are in df2 **or** df3? Which is a completely different thing, you've failed to post your desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need simply sum both list together:

```
print (df[df.id.isin(df2.capital.tolist() + df3.capital.tolist())])
  countries id
0        US  a
2   Germany  c
3     China  d
6     lanka  g
```

Another solution is use [`numpy.setxor1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setxor1d.html) - set exclusive-or of two arrays:

```
print (df[df.id.isin(np.setxor1d(df2.capital, df3.capital))])
  countries id
0        US  a
2   Germany  c
3     China  d
6     lanka  g
```

Or solution with comment with `or` - `|`:

```
print (df[(df.id.isin(df2.capital)) | (df.id.isin(df3.capital))])
  countries id
0        US  a
2   Germany  c
3     China  d
6     lanka  g
```

Comment: why i am getting empty dataframe when running EdChum code?

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: your code `print (df[df.id.isin(df2.capital.tolist() + df3.capital.tolist())])` is giving me the desired output

Comment: its giving right output by using this too `(df[(df.id.isin(df2.capital)) | (df.id.isin(df3.capital))])`